# Why can a parameter accept any construction of a typeclass but its value can't be constructed conditionally?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, haskell-req

I'm fairly new to Haskell, though not to programming, and I've been using the [req library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.1.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html) to perform HTTPS requests.

In order to retain some generality, there will be two types of request - one to create a document (via HTTP POST) and another to update a document (via HTTP PATCH, using a non-empty monoid in the `updateMask` parameter).

I can infer the HTTP verb from whether `updateMask == mempty`, but this won't compile because [`POST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.1.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html#t:POST) and [`PATCH`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.1.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html#t:PATCH) are different `data` declarations (although both are valid as the first parameter of `req` because they are instances of [`HttpMethod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.1.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html#t:HttpMethod).

```
getSaveEventRequestResponse :: Text -> Option Https -> Document -> IO IgnoreResponse
getSaveEventRequestResponse authToken updateMask document =
  runReq defaultHttpConfig $
  req
    (if updateMask == mempty
       then POST
       else PATCH)
    (https "test.example.com" /: "api" /: "projects" /: "myproject")
    (ReqBodyJson document)
    ignoreResponse $
  oAuth2Bearer (encodeUtf8 authToken) <> updateMask
```

If I swap out the `if` conditional for either one of `POST` or `PATCH` the code compiles without error.

Is there a way to make the compiler allow this conditional response or do I have to duplicate this function, one using the `POST` variant and another using the `PATCH`?

---

**Edit** for the benefit of anyone who comes to this and tries to use the same code:

The condition I used (`updateMask == mempty`) is not actually valid here, but that's not relevant to the question. The question stands if this condition is replaced by `True` or `False`.

---

**Edit 2** regarding the linked question. While I now, having got the answer, see how closely linked it is, it relies on having already considered partial application. While the principle is the same, the introduction of partial application makes it difficult for a beginner with Haskell to apply the answer there to this context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum types - Why in Haskell is \`show (Int | Double)\` different than \`(show Int) | (show Double)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783024/sum-types-why-in-haskell-is-show-int-double-different-than-show-int)

Comment: If you **really** don't want to duplicate the function, you could reach for `ExistentialQuantification`, but that will make a mess of its own.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I understand the reasoning based on that that the types are different. Is that to say that it is indeed impossible to do this without a complete duplication (excluding what has been mentioned on `ExistentialQuantification`?

Comment: You could try `(if .. then req POST else req PATCH) other args here`. This might require some type annotation to work, or simply be a hopeless attempt. I'm not familiar enough with the library to understand if this can succeed: if `AllowsBody POST` and `AllowsBody POST` are the same, it might work.

Comment: @chi Brilliant answer, this works perfectly! Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to use

```
(if updateMask == mempty then req POST else req PATCH) other args here
```

This is because

```
req :: (MonadHttp m, HttpMethod method, HttpBody body, 
        HttpResponse response, 
        HttpBodyAllowed (AllowsBody method) (ProvidesBody body))     
    => method   
    -> Url scheme   
    -> body 
    -> Proxy response   
    -> Option scheme    
    -> m response
```

Now, `AllowsBody POST` and `AllowsBody PATCH` are equal, since both are defined as `'CanHaveBody`. Therefore, both `req POST` and `req PATCH` can share a common type:

```
req POST, req PATCH 
    :: (MonadHttp m, HttpBody body, 
        HttpResponse response, 
        HttpBodyAllowed 'CanHaveBody (ProvidesBody body))    
    => Url scheme   
    -> body 
    -> Proxy response   
    -> Option scheme    
    -> m response
```

Having the same type, they can be used in the two branches of the same `if then else`.